# EF 6.0 Get by datetime

Tags: entity-framework

I want to read from the table by datetime. If I use this:

```
(from x in Db.Table where x.Date.Value == DateTime.Now select x).ToList();
```

my code throws EntityCommandExecutionException:

> A failure occurred while giving parameter information to OLE DB
>   provider

So I use this:

```
(from x in Db.Table where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DateTime.Now  select x).ToList();
```

but it is very slowly (about 40 seconds). In my table is approximately 500 000 records.

Thanks for advice

Comment: If I execute this query `select * from Table where Date = '2016-08-15' ` in SQL Management studio, it is very fast (2 second)

Comment: It is only a typo here, in my code it correctly

Comment: have you tried using `DbFunctuins.TruncateTime` on both sides? like `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)`

Comment: Yes, very slowly too.. EF generate this query: `SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Table]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Date], 102) ,  102)) = (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), SysDateTime(), 102) ,  102))) 
 OR ((convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Date], 102) ,  102) IS NULL) 
 AND (convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), SysDateTime(), 102) ,  102) IS NULL))) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define now property first and then query like following:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

var list = Db.Table.Where(e=>e.Date == now).ToList();
```

Or:

```
(from x in Db.Table where x.Date == now select x).ToList();
```

Comment: This is throw EntityCommandExecutionException: A failure occurred while giving parameter information to OLE DB provider...